# Where does Anne get this new journey book?

Tags: the-sword-of-truth

In *Faith of the Fallen*, Kahlan destroys Anne's journey book. In *Chainfire*, while talking with Richard, he mentions that this happened, and Anne(because of the plot in this book) says she accidentally dropped it in the fire. Later, she pulls out a journey book to show Nicci which has a message from Verna. Where did this other book come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's later mentioned that she fetched the book out of the fire, after Kahlan had left. It's the same journey book.

Here is the scene where it happens:

> “Dear Creator,” Ann whispered, “forgive this poor hurting child of yours for what she is about to do.”
>
> Kahlan tossed the book in the fire.
>
> With ashen faces, Ann and Sister Alessandra stood staring at the book in the hissing flames.

*Immediately following*, on the next page and the start of chapter 28, this happens:

> As soon as she saw Kahlan and Cara vanish like vengeful spirits into the whiteness, Ann fell to her knees and thrust her hands into the fire to snatch the burning journey book from its funeral pyre in the white-hot coals.
>
> “Prelate!” Alessandra cried. “You’ll burn yourself!”
>
> Flinching back from the ferocity of the pain, Ann ignored the gagging stench of burning flesh and thrust her hands again into the wavering heat of the fire. She saw, rather than felt, that she had the priceless journey book in her fingers.
>
> The entire rescue of the burning book took only a second, but, through the prism of pain, it seemed an eternity.
>
> Biting down on her lower lip against the suffering, Ann rolled to the side. Alessandra came running back with her hands full of snow. She threw it on Ann’s bloody blackened fingers and the journey book clenched in them.

Much later in the book, at the beginning of chapter 71, we find that Ann was able to restore the journey book. Verna opens her twinned journey book, and finds a message written. She writes a reply, and promptly receives the following message from Ann:

> Verna, I am well. I was able to restore the journey book with the help of some. . . people. Strange people. But the important part is that it is restored for the most part. I am still searching for the prophet. I have some good clues on Nathan’s whereabouts, and I am looking into them. But how are you, Verna? How goes the war? Warren? Kahlan? Is Zedd giving you much trouble? That man can try the patience of stone. Have you had word of Richard?

Answer (score 0):

At the end of Faith of the Fallen they make mention that some people fixed the journey book but I don't remember anything more even being said about it. I think it was going to be a part of the story line that just got dropped.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to include any relevant quotes from the book.